# How to read a SOD file created with later version of Scilab?

Tags: save, scilab

I am using two versions of Scilab : 6.1 and 5.5. (because 6.1 has the `fromJSON` function)

In 6.1, I save a structure in a SOD file, [the format used by Scilab since 5.2](https://help.scilab.org/docs/6.1.0/fr_FR/save_format.html).

```
save('path/to/file.sod', 'variable')
```

In 5.5, I need to read this structure to use it elsewhere.

```
load('path/to/file.sod', 'variable')
```

But this returns the error `listvar_in_hdf5 : Wrong version of SOD file. Max value expected : 2. found : 3`

Is there a way to specify the version of SOD format to use for saving or loading ? or another way to save data in 6.1 and load it in 5.5 ?
I tried using hdf5 but I did not succeed. It seems that I can't manage structures.

Thanks !

Comment: Why do you need to import this data back to 5.5 version ?

Comment: My company set a requirement to use Scilab 5.5 for the processing of the structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your problem is specific to structs, you can solve it by saving to the Matlab v7 format. Here is an example where data file is created in Scilab 6.1.1

```
--> getversion
 ans  =

  "scilab-6.1.1"

--> x=struct("a",1,"b",2); savematfile("data.mat","x","-v7")
```

then loaded in Scilab 5.5.2:

```
-->getversion
 ans  =
 
 scilab-5.5.2   
 
-->loadmatfile data.mat; x
 x  =
 
   a: 1
   b: 2
```