# Plot a new color for every single data loop and add value points

Tags: loops, plot, colors, figure, scilab

i've got a bunch of Measurement Data which I would like to plot in one figure. Each measurement should have a new color.
How can I plot a new color for each loop? Additional I want to see each datapoint with a marker point.

First,
I tried to use RGB Values as a color vector.

BUT it did not work.

cmap=rainbowcolormap(size(datfiles,'*'))

```
for k = 1:size(Data,'*')
// read all data1,data2,data3,data4.....
    execstr(["xvalues=data"+string(k)+"(:,1);"])
    execstr(["yvalues=data"+string(k)+"(:,2);"])

    plot2d(xvalues,yvalues,style=color(cmap(k,:)))
end
```

Then I figured out , that **plot2d(xvalues,yvalues,k)** is the solution, for k representing a new color in the loop for each plotted line.

```
j=1;
for k = 1:size(Data,'*')
    execstr(["xvalues=data"+string(k)+"(:,1);"])
    execstr(["yvalues=data"+string(k)+"(:,2);"])

    plot2d(xvalues,yvalues,k)
    
    legendstring(j)=strcat(['Measurementnr = ',string(j)]);
    j=j+1;
end

legend(legendstring,4)
```

**
*But, do you know, how to plot each measurement with different color and marker points for each value instead of having a solid line.***
I would like to see the measurement rate.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this (BTW you don't need a new index `j`, using `k` is ok). Define a bigger `mark` vector depending on the number of curves you have (answer updated for Scilab 6.1.1):

```
mark = ["o","*","^","v"]
for k = 1:size(Data,'*')
    execstr(["xvalues=data"+string(k)+"(:,1);"])
    execstr(["yvalues=data"+string(k)+"(:,2);"])

    plot(xvalues,yvalues,mark(k));
    gce().children(1).mark_foreground=addcolor(cmap(k,:));
    
    legendstring(k)=strcat(['Measurementnr = ',string(k)]);
end

legend(legendstring,4)
```

Allowed markers are

```
"+","o","*",".","x","s","d","^","v",">","<","p"
```

Comment: Thank you for your kind support! 
If I try your approach, i'll get following error message:

"
--> plot(xvalues,yvalues,'*',"markforeground",cmap(i,:))
at line   162 of function setPlotProperty ( C:\Program Files\scilab-6.1.1\modules\graphics\macros\setPlotProperty.sci line 174 )
at line   504 of function plot            ( C:\Program Files\scilab-6.1.1\modules\graphics\macros\plot.sci line 517 )

Undefined operation for the given operands.
check or define function %c_a_s for overloading.
"

Comment: Following command gives me a line without markers.
plot(xvalues,yvalues,'*',"markforeground")
This comand plot2d creates nice colors for each created plot, unfortunately without markers
plot2d(xvalues,yvalues,i*3)

Comment: Use the latest version of Scilab (2023.0.0) there will be no problem. [r,g,b] vectors for "markforeground" property is a new feature.

Comment: Thank you I would like to try that, but in this new Scilab Version I get new problems like installing atomsInstal('visa') and reading the variable name with listvarinfile, like in this post: 
I cannot comment there, because i m still a starter in stackoverflow

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70753325/how-to-read-a-sod-file-created-with-later-version-of-scilab

Comment: I have updated the answer for Scilab 6.

Comment: Hello Stéphane, can you help me again. I tried following in order to expand the marker automaticly.
element="-";
mark = repmat(element,1,size(Data,'*'));

Can you use different colors for each plot, without markers. If I use the marker "-", it will not be colored?

If you

Comment: Hello Stéphane, how can you create different colors for each line without markers?

Comment: Did you have a look to https://help.scilab.org/polyline_properties ?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Stéphane,

This is my solution now.

```
m=5:10:50;
x=0:0.01:10;

cmap=rainbowcolormap(size(m,'*'))
//mark = ["o","*","^","v"];
element = 'o';
mark = repmat(element,1,size(m,'*'));

for k=1:size(m,'*')

    y=m(k)*x;
    plot(x,y,mark(k));
    gce().children(1).mark_foreground=addcolor(cmap(k,:));
    
end


n = 10; // Anzahl der Kurven
x = linspace(0, 2*%pi, 100); // x-Werte für die Kurven

for i = 1:n
    y = sin(i*x); // y-Werte für die i-te Kurve
    color = hsv2rgb([(i-1)/(n-1), 1, 1]); // Berechne die Farbe basierend auf dem HSV-Farbraum
    
    
    plot(x, y, 'Color', color); // Zeichne die Kurve mit der entsprechenden Farbe
    
end
```